# Redirect 301 in link

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, web

I would like make redirect 301 for address:

```
http://example.com/?test=123sdf
```

to:

```
http://example.com/
```

How can i make it? I try:

```
Redirect 301 /?test=123sdf http://example.com/
```

but this not working. I would like add this in my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule` only matches REQUEST_URI with query string. You will need `RewriteCond` to match query. Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^test=123sdf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Strange, it doesn't work now. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test=123sdf$ / [R=301]
```